# Microsoft.Advertising.Mobile.UI - VS 2015 CTP 6

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-runtime

When I load a WinRT WP8 projet using `AdControl`s into Visual Studio 2015 CTP 6 (fully updated), Intellisense tells me that he can't find the namespace `Microsoft.Advertising.Mobile.UI`.

Actually, the SDK still referenced from VS 2013 in the project, but the reference is not found. And I can't find any links to download it through the web.

Does anyone know a way to install it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure that you're aware of where, `Microsoft.Advertising.Mobile.UI` would work only with `Windows Phone 8.1` RT/Silverlight as well as `WP8/7` Silverlight apps.

Reference: [API Reference - Windows Phone Advertising SDK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/advertising-mobile-windows-phone-api-reference%28v=msads.20%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

If you're in the correct path then try downloading the `Microsoft Advertising SDK` from [msdn](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8729).